# How to set custom color picker color from a string?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-extended-toolkit

I'm using the custom `ColorPicker` control provided by the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

I have a configuration file where the application take the color, this color is in string format, like: `#FFF0E68C`.

Now I'm trying to convert the string in color and valorize the `ColorPicker` color in this way:

```
var converter = new BrushConverter();
var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFF0E68C");
MyColorPicker.SelectedColor = brush;
```

but on the last line I get this error:

> Implicit conversion from the type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' in 'System.Windows.Media.Color?'

I doesn't have any `Media.Color` in `brush`, how can I fix this? Maybe someone know a better solution for achieve this target?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Mixim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140473/mixim) suggested, I simply solve the problem in this way:

```
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(settings.SyncCalendarColor);
MyColorPicker.SelectedColor = color;
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you donn't need to use BrushConverter and Brush, you should use [ColorConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and Color